# Weird keyboard in Safari iPhone X for html5 input type date

Tags: ios, html, keyboard, iphone-x

In Safari or UIWebView on iPhone X (iOS 11.2.6) the default keyboard for html5 date input has a weird layout (please see the area outlined with a red rectangle in the screenshot below).

Is this a bug in Apple's UI? Is there any way to fix this?

[image: Clear and Done labels obstructed/munged]

Comment: Can you add the iOS version number to the question?

Comment: Thank you! I already updated

Comment: If you don't have access to XCode, try using a third-party simulator, like [Appetize](https://appetize.io/). Also, please include images in your post rather than linking to an off-site resource.

Comment: @chb I tested on simulator and real device and this error happen on iPhoneX only. Also I'm a new member, my account don't have enough permission to post a Image, sorry for that.

Comment: @Rec No, it's I who owe you an apology. I should be more familiar with what new users can and cannot do on the site.

Comment: @Rec I am also having the same issue. Did you find the solution?

Comment: @Sudhir I didn't found the solution. Still waiting for Apple to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

This is an iOS 11 bug which was fixed in iOS 12. Not sure about iOS 12.0, but on iOS 12.1 it looks good.